# narrow casting int to smaller types

Tags: java, casting

If every operand in assignment and mathematical operations, before the expression performed, promote to `int` (if it doesn't have `L, f, d` flags);

And putting an `int` into a smaller primitive type (such as `byte`) should be done with `narrow-casting`;

So how the following assignment works?

```
byte a = 100;
```

If 100 is an integer, so putting it into a byte needs casting.

Comment: It's a narrowing conversion, not casting; casting doesn't change the target value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte a = 100;
```

This works because...

If the right-hand side in an [assignment context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) is a constant expression,

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Where

> Literals of primitive type [...]

are a [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

And the [range of a byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) is

> [...] from `-128` to `127`, inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte a = 100;
```

This works because byte range in java is from`-128 to 127`,so if you assign value upto 127,there is no need for cast.

Try to assign `128`,you will get compiler error.

```
byte a = 128 ; //compiler error(incompatible type)
byte a = (byte)128;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a compile-time constant, and the compiler can determine that it'll fit in a byte. This actually did require a narrowing conversion in older versions of Java.

Comment: So if it is a constant, compiler know does it fit or not, but if it's an expression, it forces to cast after performing the result?